# C++: implement a bool template parameter in virtual function

Tags: c++, templates, macros

A performance bottleneck of my program is frequent calls to functions like following `update` functions.
Given that `flag` parameter is always a bool literal, I want to "unroll" the `update` function to two versions, one with `flag=true` and one with `flag=false`, to avoid branch prediction failure.

for normal functions, a bool template parameter can solve this problem easily.
However, template cannot be applied to virtual functions.

I can create two virtual functions manually, but then I have to copy the `long code` part. It makes futher development harder.

Is there anyway allowing me to write two versions in one function, controlled by a compiling-time constant `flag`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct Base
{
    virtual void update(bool flag) = 0;
};

struct Derived1 : public Base
{
    void update(bool flag)
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            // some computations
            cout << "Derived1 flag=true" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            // some computations
            cout << "Derived1 flag=false" << endl;
        }

        // long code containing several flag-conditioned blocks like the block above
        cout << "Derived1" << endl;
    }
};

struct Derived2 : public Base
{
    void update(bool flag)
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            // some computations
            cout << "Derived2 flag=true" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            // some computations
            cout << "Derived2 flag=false" << endl;
        }

        // long code containing several flag-conditioned blocks like the block above
        cout << "Derived2" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base *p;
    srand(time(nullptr));
    if (rand() % 2 == 1)
    {
        p = new Derived1();
    }
    else
    {
        p = new Derived2();
    }
    p->update(false);
    p->update(true);
}
```

Comment: Virtual functions can't be templates, but you can simply call a private non-virtual function template in the implementation of the two virtual functions to avoid code duplication of `long code`.

Comment: Maybe you can use function overloading using `std::true_type` and `std::false_type` using `std::bool_constant<>`?

Comment: If a template could generate a virtual method, what would the corresponding VMT look like…?

Comment: Have you profile the `update()` thoroughly? I double the `if` part is bottleneck... Probably there are some other things you should check. Eg: Use `"...\n"` instead of `std::endl` which causes a `flush()` to `ostream`.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek For single bool parameter, I expect it can be specialized to two virtual functions. The template is only used to control their logic difference in `if (flag)` way.

Comment: @LouisGo Sorry for the confusion. `cout` lines here only represent some general calculations.

Comment: Then please profile the "general calculations" instead of assuming the `if` is the bottle neck. Unless you're pretty sure that the code without `if` works much faster. Eg: commenting out the `if` but leave the calculations in code. I still double that `if` worth the template tricks. For example, if you have a logging system, mostly all the evaluations on logging levels are done in runtime but it should not impact performance in a noticable order. The post doesn't include much context, but it's less likely `if` happens to be bottleneck unless your writing code in kernel or time critical prog.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such thing as virtual templates. What can be done however is to create several virtual functions taking an integral (boolean in this particular case) constant, if the flag is really a compile time literal:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

using std::cout;

struct Base
{
    virtual void updateSeparate(std::true_type) = 0;
    virtual void updateSeparate(std::false_type) = 0;
};

struct Derived1 : public Base
{

    void updateSeparate(std::true_type)
    {
        cout << "Derived1 flag=true\n";
        updateCommonImpl();
    }

    void updateSeparate(std::false_type)
    {
        cout << "Derived1 flag=false\n";
        updateCommonImpl();
    }

private: 
    void updateCommonImpl() //or just a static function inside implementation file if members are not used
    {
        cout << "Derived1\n";
    }
};

struct Derived2 : public Base
{
    void updateSeparate(std::true_type)
    {
        cout << "Derived2 flag=true\n";
        updateCommonImpl();
    }

    void updateSeparate(std::false_type)
    {
        cout << "Derived2 flag=false\n";
        updateCommonImpl();
    }
private:
    void updateCommonImpl() //or just a static function inside implementation file if members are not used
    {
        cout << "Derived2\n";
    }

};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> p;
    srand(time(nullptr));
    if (rand() % 2 == 1)
    {
        p = std::make_unique<Derived1>();
    }
    else
    {
        p = std::make_unique<Derived2>();
    }
    p->updateSeparate(std::bool_constant<false>{});
    p->updateSeparate(std::bool_constant<true>{});
}
```

[DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/Yb91TK34h)
However, I cannot tell if that will help or maybe hinder the performance even more by making the vtable lookup time even longer, you have to experiment with that by yourself I'm afraid.

Comment: Why? Just give the functions different names. `updateYes()` says exactly the same thing `updateSeparate(std::bool_constant<true>{})` does, in 1/4 of the space.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement a CRTP pattern with `constexpr` template parameter, please take a look

```
template<typename T>
struct Base {
    template<bool flag>
    int update() {
        return static_cast<T*>(this)->template updateImpl<flag>();
    }
};


struct Derived1 : public Base<Derived1> {
    template<bool flag>
    constexpr int updateImpl() { 
        if constexpr (flag) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 2;
        }
    }
};


struct Derived2 : public Base<Derived2> {  
    template<bool flag>
    constexpr int updateImpl() {
        return 3;
    }

};

int main() {
    auto obj1 = new Derived1();
    std::cout << obj1->update<true>(); // 1
    std::cout << obj1->update<false>(); // 2
 
    auto obj2 = new Derived2();
    std::cout << obj2->update<true>(); // 3
    std::cout << obj2->update<false>(); // 3
}
```

Comment: Of course when you CRTP, there is no longer a common base class, and without a common base class, there is no need for a virtual function, so if we assume no need for a virtual function, the function can be a template in the first place, without introducing CRTP.